# Android | How to show a disclaimer note on swiping from one tab to another

Tags: android

I am developing a android application with 3 tabs. On opening the application it lands on Home tab. What I want is when I try to swipe to the second tab, before landing on that tab I want to show a disclaimer note. I want the disclaimer note only on that tab and only 1 time. Please help.

Comment: what is the `position` of  your `homeTab`

Comment: @VishalYadav position of home tab is 1 and I want the note before landing into the 2nd tab (no need in 3rd tab)

Comment: The note will have one ok button and on clicking on that button 2nd tab will appear.

Comment: you want to show a `message` before appearing of `second` tab ..... i am right ?

Comment: yes. The message should have a **ok** button and only clicking on that button the **second** tab should appear.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this it was helpful for you

---

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            String str_selectedTab=tab.getPosition()+"";
            switch (str_selectedTab){
                case "0":
                   
                    break;
                case "1":
                    showAlert();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    
                    break;
               
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    private void showAlert(){
//your Dialog HEre
Your_View_Pager_Obj.setCurrentItem(2);
}
```